# which column is a duplicate column a duplicate of?

Tags: r, duplicates

I have a data frame with possibly several duplicated columns.
I would like to do 2 thing (the following is a reproducible example, in practice I have dozens of columns):

First, Extract the unique columns. This can efficiently be accomplished with the following command:

```
library(dplyr)
df = data_frame(x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100), z = y, w = x)
df[!duplicated(as.list(df))]
```

This outputs columns `x` and `y`.

Next, I would like to find specifically which is the duplicate of `x` (`w`) and which is the duplicate of `y` (`z`). How can I do this efficiently?

Comment: I think you mean that w is a duplicate of x and z is a duplicate of y.

Comment: How about `cor(df)`?

Comment: `cor` detects columns which can be multiples of each other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very similar to the answer provided by @Sotos

```
library(dplyr)

# example data
df = data_frame(x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100), z = y, w = x)

# function to compare vectors
f = function(x,y) { all(df[,x] == df[,y]) }

# vectorise function
f = Vectorize(f)


data.frame(t(combn(names(df),2)), stringsAsFactors = F) %>%
  mutate(flag = f(X1, X2))

#   X1 X2  flag
# 1  x  y FALSE
# 2  x  z FALSE
# 3  x  w  TRUE
# 4  y  z  TRUE
# 5  y  w FALSE
# 6  z  w FALSE
```

You can then focus on the pairs where the flag is TRUE.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `combn` to get all combinations between your columns. Once you have that, there are various metrics to catch equality. Since you are dealing with floats, I would suggest to use  correlation. If it is 1 then the 2 columns are the same, i.e.

```
setNames(combn(df, 2, FUN = function(i) all(cor(i) == 1)), 
         combn(names(df), 2, FUN = toString))

# x, y  x, z  x, w  y, z  y, w  z, w 
#FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

If correlation is not enough, then we can add the variance in there as well, i.e.

```
setNames(combn(df, 2, FUN = function(i) all(cor(i) == 1) & length(unique(as.vector(var(i)))) == 1), 
         combn(names(df), 2, toString))

# x, y  x, z  x, w  y, z  y, w  z, w 
#FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

You can structure the output any way you want.

Comment: I was waiting for a clever solution

Comment: what if the column are not the same but multiples of each other? then the correlation is also 1. I have to know specifically if they are identical

Comment: @OmryAtia Updated by throwing variance in as well. That should take care of it